# parameters in defer function in loops when using twisted

Tags: python, twisted

parameters confuse me a lot when i using defer function with twisted.

i consider if the function's parameter is a **INT-VALUE**, or other basic types besides of list and dict, it should pass-by value not reference.

```
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor

def deferFunc(x):
    print "11111 %d" % x
    d = defer.Deferred()
    reactor.callLater(1, d.callback, x)
    return d

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def inlineDeferFunc(x):
    print "11111 %d" % x
    d = defer.Deferred()
    reactor.callLater(1, d.callback, x)
    result = yield d
    defer.returnValue(result)

def loop():
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    d = defer.succeed(0)
    for i in x:
        d.addCallback(lambda _ : inlineDeferFunc(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop()

    try:
        reactor.run()
    except:
        reactor.stop()
```

the result is :

```
11111 1
11111 4
11111 4
11111 4
```

and the result confused me.

how can i get the right output like 1,2,3,4

Comment: by the way i found 

       `d.addCallback(lambda _ : inlineDeferFunc(x[0]))\
 .addCallback(lambda _ : inlineDeferFunc(x[1]))\
 .addCallback(lambda _ : inlineDeferFunc(x[2]))\
 .addCallback(lambda _ : inlineDeferFunc(x[3]))\`

this would work fine. so i think it's something related to the **for** loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can i get the right output like 1,2,3,4

like this:

```
def loop():
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    d = defer.succeed(0)
    for i in x:
        d.addCallback(lambda _, i = i : inlineDeferFunc(i))



11111 1
11111 2
11111 3
11111 4
```

note that we are copying the values in the function definition `i = i`.
the problem was that the `lambda` grabs the parent environment to access the variable `i` after all how it would know what value it is, for performance reasons I don't think it copies it during definition, but the parent environment keeps being updated by the `for` loop.

here is a simple test.

```
>>> def test_closures():
...     i = 2
...     def test():
...         return i
...     i = 3
...     return test
... 
>>> test_closures()()
3
```